# Adding separate conditions for each item in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have 3 collections.

The user_movie collection keeps the relationship of the user and the movies he added to his list. The membership_date field is when the user is subscribed.

- The user wants to see the reviews of the movies he added to his list.
- But when showing these reviews, I want to show the comments after the subscription date.

With the query I tried, the user sees all the reviews.

Collection structure

```
db={
  "user_movie": [
   {
    "_id" : 1,
    "movie_id" : 1,
    "user_id" : 1,
    "status" : true,
    "membership_date" : ISODate("2021-01-01")
    },
    {
    "_id" : 2,
    "movie_id" : 2,
    "user_id" : 1,
    "status" : true,
    "membership_date" :  ISODate("2021-01-01")
    },
    {
    "_id" : 3,
    "movie_id" : 3,
    "user_id" : 1,
    "status" : true,
    "membership_date" :  ISODate("2022-01-02")
    }
  ],
  "movie": [
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "movie_name" : "fugiat nulla",
    },
    {
        "_id" : 2,
        "movie_name" : "sint occaecat",
    },
    {
        "_id" : 3,
        "movie_name" : "cupidatat non",
    }
  ],
  "movie_reviews": [
   {
        "_id" : 1,
        "movie_id" : 1,
        "review": "Lorem ipsum dolor"
        "review_date" : ISODate("2021-01-02"),
    },
    {
        "_id" : 2,
        "movie_id" : 2,
        "review": "Consectetur adipiscing elit"
        "review_date" : ISODate("2021-01-02"),
    },
    {
        "_id" : 3,
        "movie_id" : 3,
        "review": "Do eiusmod tempor"
        "review_date" : ISODate("2021-01-02"),
    },
    {
        "_id" : 4,
        "movie_id" : 3,
        "review": "Abore et dolore magna"
        "review_date" : ISODate("2022-01-01"),
    }
  ]
}
```

The query I tried gives this output.

```
[
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "movie_id" : 1,
        "date" : ISODate("2021-01-02"),
    },
    {
        "_id" : 2,
        "movie_id" : 2,
        "date" : ISODate("2021-01-02"),
    },
    {
        "_id" : 3,
        "movie_id" : 3,
        "date" : ISODate("2021-01-02"),
    },
    {
        "_id" : 4,
        "movie_id" : 3,
        "date" : ISODate("2022-01-01"),
    }
]
```

But this is not the output I was expecting. The movie reviews with id 3,4 should not be seen by the user. Because it was written before the membership_date date, so the user should not see these reviews.

How can I get all movie reviews of the user with id 1 as mentioned?

Comment: I think movie review id:4 will appear, as its `review_date` is greater than the `membership-date` for `user_movie` id: 3.

Comment: I typed wrong. Thank you for informing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Stage 1: [`$lookup` with pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#perform-multiple-joins-and-a-correlated-subquery-with--lookup)**

- Join conditions:

1. By `movie_id`.
2. `movie_review`'s `review_date` must not be earlier (`$gte`) than `membership_date` (from `user_movie`).

**Stage 2: `$unwind`**

- Deconstruct `movie_reviews` array field to multiple document.

**Stage 3: `$replaceWith`**

- Decorate the output document to show `movie_review` document.

```
db.user_movie.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "movie_reviews",
      let: {
        movie_id: "$movie_id",
        membership_date: "$membership_date"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$movie_id",
                    "$$movie_id"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $gte: [
                    "$review_date",
                    "$$membership_date"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "movie_reviews"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$movie_reviews"
  },
  {
    "$replaceWith": "$movie_reviews"
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yzrsPN2JzTT)

---

**Updated: Lookup join `movie_reviews` with `user_movie`**

Since you are just to get `movie_reviews`, I think it is better to join from `movie_reviews` with `user_movie` instead of joining from `user_movie`  with `movie_reviews` to get rid of the use of `$unwind`.

```
db.movie_reviews.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "user_movie",
      let: {
        movie_id: "$movie_id",
        review_date: "$review_date"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$movie_id",
                    "$$movie_id"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $gte: [
                    "$$review_date",
                    "$membership_date"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "user_movie"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "user_movie": {
        $ne: []
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      user_movie: 0
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (Get movie_reviews)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Vod_9kdX-Dn)

Comment: thank you very much.  It worked as I expected.  Do you think the performance of this query will be an issue?  In general, there are 2000-3000 reviews for each movie.

Comment: Hi, I had updated my answer, I think Lookup join `movie_reviews` with `user_movie` will be better as able to get rid `$unwind` which possible affect the query performance.

Comment: Hi, Thank you. The version with "unwind" works much faster. With 50 thousand data, the first query is completed in 1.67 seconds and the second query in 18 seconds.